# How do I call an injected constructor without parameters?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, constructor-injection

I have the following constructor, where ISession is configured to resolve to an NHibernate session:

```
public EntityStore(ISession session)
{
    Session = session;
}
```

The `UnityConfig` is as follows:

```
container.RegisterType<ISessionFactory>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(sf => new NhibernateSessionFactory().GetSessionFactory()));
```

Now I would, for some reason, expect Unity to inject a session when I call the constructor as follows:

```
Claims = new EntityStore<TClaim, TKey>();
```

Could someone please help this absolute Unity novice on how to achieve what I describe above?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your object to be created using Unity, you need to call one of `Resolve` methods. In your case you can do something like this:

```
Claims = container.Resolve<EntityStore<TClaim, TKey>>();
```

or

```
var s = container.Resolve<ISessionFactory>();
var Claims = new EntityStore<TClaim, TKey>(s);
```

There are two downsides to this approach. First, you you need to have access to `container` in your class, which is not always possible. Second, you are creating dependencies inside the class, which makes it to keep track of all dependencies.

Better approach would be to have all your dependencies injected as constructor parameters or properties, and use `container.Resolve` only in top level elements (e.g. Application class or main form). In this case you could replace your class so it injects `EntityStore<TClaim, TKey>` as constructor parameter:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public YourClass(EntityStore<TClaim, TKey> store)
    {
        // save reference to store and use it later
    }
}
```

Comment: Having to call `Resolve` myself seems to take quite a bit away from the magic I thought Unity was supposed to be doing for me.

Comment: @ProfK Unity does the magic when you use the container. When you instantiate class yourself using a constructor, it has nothing to do with using Unity, it is just simple instantiation of a class

Comment: How would you recommend I maintain the container? A singleton globally available?

Comment: @ProfK Singleton is one of the approaches. Configuring container and registering all dependencies often takes significant time, so it is a bad idea to configure new container for every web request (I guess you have a web application?). Better approach is to configure container once and reuse the same instance everywhere.